# On the $R$-module $R:=\mathrm{M}_2(\Bbb C)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, modules, noncommutative-algebra

We take the ring $R:=\mathrm{M}_2(\Bbb C)$, we regard it as a $R$-module over itself, and we take  its simple $R$-module $K:=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \Bbb C \\ 0 & \Bbb C\end{pmatrix} \leq \mathrm{M}_2(\Bbb C)$. If $0\neq \alpha \in R$ is *not* invertible matrix, we want to show that there exists an invertible matrix $\beta \in R$, such that $\alpha \beta \in K$.

To prove that, it might be useful the facts one can see: $\alpha \in \mathrm{GL_2}(\Bbb C) \iff R\alpha=R$ and $\forall y\in K\backslash\{0\}$ it is $Ry=K$.

But how could we go further?

Comment: If $(e_1,e_2)$ is the canonical basis of $\mathbb{C}^2$, the matrices in $K$ are exactly those having $e_1$ in their kernel. If a matrix is not invertible, try to take a non-zero vector in its kernel and to relate it to $e_1$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: Try to think about it. It is a very basic exercise of linear algebra, it should not pose any problem for someone studying rings and modules.

Comment: Well. As you said we firstly observe that $K:=\{\gamma \in R: \pmatrix{1 \\ 0} \in \ker \gamma\}.$ Now, since $\alpha \notin \mathrm{GL}_2 (\Bbb C) \iff \ker \alpha \neq \{0\}$. So, there exists a non-zero matrix $x\in \ker \alpha \iff \alpha x =0$. But now? Also I can see that $\alpha \beta \in K \iff \pmatrix{1 \\ 0} \in \ker \alpha \beta \iff \alpha \beta \pmatrix{1 \\ 0} = 0 $.

Comment: Well, if you know there is some $x\neq 0$ such that $\alpha(x)=0$, can't you find some invertible $\beta$ such that $\alpha\beta(e_1)=0$? It just requires $\beta(e_1)=x$.

Comment: Do you mean by $\alpha (x) =0$ the matrix multiplication of $a $ by $x$?